# Can we derive service limits for Oracle OCI using CLI or API

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

My requirement is to derive service limits like network limits, storage limits for a tenancy on Oracle cloud infrastructure(OCI). Is it possible to fetch the same using OCI CLI or API

Comment: Please get in touch via email, address is in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing service limits is currently limited to the console, see https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  Here is what you need to check service limits:
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-
cli/2.24.0/oci_cli_docs/cmdref/limits.html

For everything ins Oracle OCI you have following options

1. OCI CLI - https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/oci-cli/2.24.0/oci_cli_docs/index.html
2. OCI SDKs (Java, Python, .NET, GO Ruby, TypeScript)
   https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#
   https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/typescript/2.5.1/globals.html
   https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdks.htm
3. Terraform provider
   https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs